# UISearchBar that behaves as a UISearchController using storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

There's a page I'm designing that uses a search bar that's intended to work as a UISearchController. The search bar is positioned in the center of a view. When a user taps the search bar, I want the search bar to move from the center to the top, and display the results controller as the user is inputting data, to return the filtered results.

I'm using a storyboard to piece this all together and the only option I see is a searchbar, not a search controller. Is it possible to configure the searchbar (IBOutlet) to function the same way as a UISearchController? If not, how should I approach this scenario properly?